# How to update a column in an Oracle table from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table named PENSION with the following data

```
PERSNO MMYY AMT   STNO
C01234 0120 1000  null
C01234 0220 1100  null
C01234 0320 1050  null
C02563 0120 1000  null
C02563 0220 950   null
C02563 0320 1200  null
```

and I have another table EMPLOYEE with the following data

```
PERSNO STNO
C01234 1521
C02563 2365
C01891 2593
```

I need to update the STNO field of PENSION table with the value of the field STNO of EMPLOYEE table whenever there is a match between PERSNO field of PENSION and EMPLOYEE tables.

Can someone please suggest me the SQL query to perform this operation in Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice `MERGE` option:

```
merge into pension p
using employee e
on (p.persno = e.persno)
when matched then 
update set p.stno = e.stno;
```

---

With sample data you posted (slightly modified; didn't feel like typing that much):

```
SQL> select * From pension;

PERSNO       STNO        AMT
------ ---------- ----------
c01234                     1
c01234                     3
c01234                     5
c02563                     2
c02563                     9
c02563                     2

6 rows selected.

SQL> select * From employee;

PERSNO       STNO
------ ----------
c01234       1521
c02563       2365
c01891       2593

SQL> merge into pension p
  2  using employee e
  3  on (p.persno = e.persno)
  4  when matched then
  5  update set p.stno = e.stno;

6 rows merged.

SQL> select * from pension;

PERSNO       STNO        AMT
------ ---------- ----------
c01234       1521          1
c01234       1521          3
c01234       1521          5
c02563       2365          2
c02563       2365          9
c02563       2365          2

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

But, if there's a duplicate `PERSNO` in the `EMPLOYEE` table:

```
SQL> select * from employee order by persno;

PERSNO       STNO
------ ----------
c01234       1521      --> two rows for 
c01234       9999      --> c01234
c01891       2593
c02563       2365
```

Query doesn't work any more because it can't decide which of those two rows to use. Do **you** know? If so, tell us. Or, if duplicates aren't allowed, get rid of them and `merge` will work again.

```
SQL> merge into pension p
  2  using employee e
  3  on (p.persno = e.persno)
  4  when matched then
  5  update set p.stno = e.stno;
merge into pension p
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables


SQL>
```

If you decide to select e.g. `MIN(EMPLOYEE.STNO)` value, then you'd rewrite query as

```
SQL> merge into pension p
  2  using (select e.persno, min(e.stno) stno
  3         from employee e
  4         group by e.persno
  5        ) x
  6  on (p.persno = x.persno)
  7  when matched then
  8  update set p.stno = x.stno;

6 rows merged.

SQL>
```

and it'll work again.

Comment: It gives the error: Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
30926. 00000 -  "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"
*Cause:    A stable set of rows could not be got because of large dml
           activity or a non-deterministic where clause.
*Action:   Remove any non-deterministic where clauses and reissue the dml.

Comment: It means that you have duplicates (per PERSNO) in the EMPLOYEE table. Is that allowed? If so, which row do you want to use? Because, according to sample data you posted, it *works* OK. See the edited answer.

Comment: How to get this query right, in case duplicate entries exist in the employee table.

Comment: You have to get rid of them, somehow. Either delete them, or rewrite MERGE so that it uses one STNO per employee - for example, MIN(STNO). I edited the answer and added that example to the end, have a look.